# I am having this referenced before assignment error in my code and I can't get it to work even after implementing the "global"

Tags: python, global-variables

[RESOLVED]
I can't seem to get it to work as I've done as they've said in [this post][1], it was previously working until I added the "BfToAA" section, which is a modified copy of the "BfToARN", I don't think I got any error as this global fix was enough for before, I leave all my code next for you to see and maybe give advice on making it work.

```
#This is my "main"
def ElegirCamino():
    
    #here you can input your brainF*ck code that is going to be translated
    print("Inserte usted su código en notación especificada en el  README.txt")
    códigoBf = input()
    
    #here the code is sent to be translated to ARN by the convention that I've made.
    i=0
    print("El anterior código traducido a ARN según los datos datos en el README.txt es:")
    while i<len(códigoBf):
        BfToARN(códigoBf[i], i)
        i += 1
    códigoARN = códigoARN + "UAA"
    print(códigoARN)


    #here the code is sent to be translated to nucleic acids by the convention that I've made.
    i=0
    print("Lo que en ácidos nucléicos es:")
    while i<len(códigoBf):
        BfToAA(códigoBf[i], i)
        i += 1
    códigoAA = códigoAA + "STOP"
    print(códigoAA)

    

def BfToARN(Bf, i):
    if i==0:
        global códigoARN 
        códigoARN = "AUG"

    if(Bf == '+'):
        códigoARN = códigoARN + "UUU"
    elif(Bf == '-'):
        códigoARN = códigoARN + "UUA"
    elif(Bf == '.'):
        códigoARN = códigoARN + "UCU"
    elif(Bf == ','):
        códigoARN = códigoARN + "UAU"
    elif(Bf == '['):
        códigoARN = códigoARN + "UGU"
    elif(Bf == ']'):
        códigoARN = códigoARN + "UGG"
    elif(Bf == '<'):
        códigoARN = códigoARN + "CCU"
    elif(Bf == '>'):
        códigoARN = códigoARN + "CGU"
    else:
        print("    ERROR. Se esperaba uno de los caracteres del lenguaje Bf pero se ha encontrado un: \""+ Bf + "\"")

def BfToAA(Bf, i):
    if i==0:
        global códigoAA 
        códigoAA = "Met "

    if(Bf == '+'):
        códigoAA = códigoAA + "Phe "
    elif(Bf == '-'):
        códigoAA = códigoAA + "Leu "
    elif(Bf == '.'):
        códigoAA = códigoAA + "Ser "
    elif(Bf == ','):
        códigoAA = códigoAA + "Tyr "
    elif(Bf == '['):
        códigoAA = códigoAA + "Cys "
    elif(Bf == ']'):
        códigoAA = códigoAA + "Trp "
    elif(Bf == '<'):
        códigoAA = códigoAA + "Pro "
    elif(Bf == '>'):
        códigoAA = códigoAA + "Arg "
    else:
        print("    ERROR. Se esperaba uno de los caracteres del lenguaje Bf pero se ha encontrado un: \""+ Bf + "\"")

ElegirCamino()
```

Thanks to everybody that anwsered and helped me understeand my mistakes here.
[1]: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/171863/local-variable-referenced-before-assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main mistake is assigning globals in the condition statement and not including the global keywords in your "main" function. I modified your code so that it runs. Take notice of where the global keyword is in both of the functions.

```
#This is my "main"
def ElegirCamino():
    global códigoARN
    global códigoAA
    #here you can input your brainF*ck code that is going to be translated
    print("Inserte usted su código en notación especificada en el  README.txt")
    códigoBf = input()

    #here the code is sent to be translated to ARN by the convention that I've made.
    i=0
    print("El anterior código traducido a ARN según los datos datos en el README.txt es:")
    while i<len(códigoBf):
        BfToARN(códigoBf[i], i)
        i += 1
    códigoARN = códigoARN + "UAA"
    print(códigoARN)


    #here the code is sent to be translated to nucleic acids by the convention that I've made.
    i=0
    print("Lo que en ácidos nucléicos es:")
    while i<len(códigoBf):
        BfToAA(códigoBf[i], i)
        i += 1
    códigoAA = códigoAA + "STOP"
    print(códigoAA)

    

def BfToARN(Bf, i):
    global códigoARN 

    if i==0:
        códigoARN = "AUG"
    if(Bf == '+'):
        códigoARN = códigoARN + "UUU"
    elif(Bf == '-'):
        códigoARN = códigoARN + "UUA"
    elif(Bf == '.'):
        códigoARN = códigoARN + "UCU"
    elif(Bf == ','):
        códigoARN = códigoARN + "UAU"
    elif(Bf == '['):
        códigoARN = códigoARN + "UGU"
    elif(Bf == ']'):
        códigoARN = códigoARN + "UGG"
    elif(Bf == '<'):
        códigoARN = códigoARN + "CCU"
    elif(Bf == '>'):
        códigoARN = códigoARN + "CGU"
    else:
        print("    ERROR. Se esperaba uno de los caracteres del lenguaje Bf pero se ha encontrado un: \""+ Bf + "\"")

def BfToAA(Bf, i):
    global códigoAA 
    if i==0:
        códigoAA = "Met "
    if(Bf == '+'):
        códigoAA = códigoAA + "Phe "
    elif(Bf == '-'):
        códigoAA = códigoAA + "Leu "
    elif(Bf == '.'):
        códigoAA = códigoAA + "Ser "
    elif(Bf == ','):
        códigoAA = códigoAA + "Tyr "
    elif(Bf == '['):
        códigoAA = códigoAA + "Cys "
    elif(Bf == ']'):
        códigoAA = códigoAA + "Trp "
    elif(Bf == '<'):
        códigoAA = códigoAA + "Pro "
    elif(Bf == '>'):
        códigoAA = códigoAA + "Arg "
    else:
        print("    ERROR. Se esperaba uno de los caracteres del lenguaje Bf pero se ha encontrado un: \""+ Bf + "\"")

ElegirCamino()
```

Comment: As I see it now your response should work but it still doens't like the 13 line, the códigoARN = códigoARN + "UAA", nor does it like the same section of the AA part, do you know how could I fix this part?

Comment: You will get this error if you do not specify códigoARN's value when entering input. Try setting ```códigoARN=''``` right under the     ```global códigoAA``` on line 4.

Comment: Thank you very much, It now works and I think I understeand what I did wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
def BfToAA(Bf, i):
    global códigoAA

    if i==0:
        códigoAA = "Met "
```

you were assigning global in conditional statement which might not execute if condition is not true. Same with other functions as well

Answer (score 0):

`ElegirCamino()` doesn't know anything about `códigoARN` and `códigoAA`

It should be something like this:

[image]

The difference between global and local variables is that global var can be accessed all over but local vars can not, but here's the trick you can use `global` in python to tell the function that you're in to reference to this global var and use it as its own local variable.

I recommend reading more on the topic because there's also other ways